# Magento 2.2.3 Install in Subdirectory, admin not loading and redirect to home page

Tags: magento2

After installing Magento 2.2.3 to Magento subdirectory, I am unable to open Magento backend. Frontend is working properly but whenever I am trying to open backend it will automatically rediects me to Homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Clean install your Magento 2 installation with the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://inserturlofwebshop/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=insertdbname \
--db-user=insertdbuser --db-password=insertdbpassword \
--admin-firstname=insertname --admin-lastname=insertlastname --admin-email=insertemail \
--admin-user=insertuser --admin-password=insertpassword --language=en_EN \
--backend-frontname=insertfrontname \
--currency=EUR --timezone=Continent/City --use-rewrites=1
```

at `backend-frontname` specify the admin url.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value against the path **web/secure/base_url** in **"core_config_data"** table. If you don't have SSL enabled then secure url should have **http** and not **https**

Comment: I have ssl enabled so there is no ssl issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution using this changes.

Check web/secure/use_in_adminhtml and web/secure/use_in_frontend settings in core_config_data, they both should be set to 1.